# Java Properties проблема с чтением русских букв

Tags: java, кодировка, properties

Доброго времени суток. Есть проблема с чтением файла `Properties`, содержащего русские буквы. Слово **Нахабино** считывается как **???°???°?±??????**. Вот код:

```
Properties mProperties = new Properties();
mProperties.load(new FileInputStream(desktop + "pr.properties"));
System.out.println(mProperties.getProperty("setA"));
```

Пробовал при помощи Notepad++ менять кодировку файла на Asii, UTF-8, UTF-8 без BOM, UCS2, и ещё несколько. Результат - в одной кодировке вопросики и плюсики, в другой квадратики и кружочки и т.д. Помогите исправить ошибку.

Comment: Я работал с Properties из стандарт java api. Проблем с кодировкой не наблюдалось. Авы уверены что вывод у вас сам адекват, как я помню в винде если делать java вывод через консоль.......

Comment: Консоль у меня нормальная Java Eclipse Neon. - Вывод адекват? - не понимаю, что именно вы имеете ввиду.

Answer (score 9):

[Согласно стандарту](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)), `.properties` файлы содержат текст в кодировке ISO 8859-1. Это создает определенные трудности при работе с кириллическими символами, т.к. все тот же стандарт предписывает кодировать их как escape-последовательности Unicode. Что выглядит не очень читабельно:

```
some.key=\u0417\u043D\u0430\u0447\u0435\u043D\u0438\u0435
```

К счастью, IDE имеют функциональность (встроенную или через плагины) для прозрачного преобразования кодировки, называемую *native-to-ascii conversion*. Благодаря этому, вы можете при редактировании видеть в IDE понятный текст:

```
some.key=Значение
```

который будет фактически преобразован в текст из предыдущего примера.

При загрузке файла через класс `Properties` вы будете иметь дело уже с java-строками в Unicode и кириллица там будет такая, как вы ожидаете.

Comment: Я попробовал сделать как Вы написали (таким образом: `\u0417..`). `System.out.println` вывел мне "Нахабино", но я потом эту строку отправил в сокет и клиенту она пришла как "Íàõàáèíî".

Comment: Раз в консоль вы получили читабельный текст, значит проблема уже не в кодировке файла, а в передаче-приеме по сокету.

Comment: @L'Esperanza явно задавайте кодировки при декодировании и кодировании строк в байты

Comment: По сокету текст я отправлял так `mDataOutputStream.writeBytes(...)`

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, присоединяюсь. Указывайте кодировку явно на обоих концах.

Comment: Проблема была во втором конце. Всё решил. Сервер не я писал, а другой человек, он там намудрил. Я, в общем, создал свой класс с Properties (см. ответ ниже).

Answer (score 0):

Я создал вот такой прекрасный класс:

```
private class MyProperties {

    private File mFile;
    private ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(), values = new ArrayList<String>();

    MyProperties() throws Throwable {
        // FileInputStream fis...
        // загружаем в массивы keys и values значения
    }

    synchronized ArrayList<String> keySet() {
        return this.keys;
    }

    synchronized String getProperty(String key, String defaultValue) {
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < this.keys.size(); i1++) {
            if (this.keys.get(i1).equals(key)) {
                return this.values.get(i1);
            }
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }

    synchronized void setProperty(String key, String value) throws Throwable {
        this.values.set(this.keys.indexOf(key), value);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(this.mFile));
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < this.keys.size(); i1++) {
            out.writeBytes(this.keys.get(i1) + "=" + this.values.get(i1));
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

}
```

жить с ним просто чудо. Не надо теперь париться по поводу каких-то кодировок и русских букв. Читает всё подряд.

Comment: Создавать свои велосипеды  вместо стандартных классов, это разумеется ваш выбор, но я бы не советовал

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, предложите свой вариант решения. Я не очень люблю из-за каждой ерунды скачивать всякие API, библиотеки и т.д.) Если же мой вариант работает, почему бы и нет?..

Comment: Вы не смогли справиться с проблемой кодировки. Вместо того чтобы ее решить создали новую.  Библиотек никаких подключать не нужно, это стандартный класс и он вам дается бесплатно. Он в любом случае будет, используете его или нет. А если он есть то почему бы его не заузать? Тем более он скорее всего содержит меньше багов чем ваш класс, т.к. элементарно его используют больше людей.

Comment: почему ArrayList, а не HаshMap?

Comment: Я досих не понимаю этот класс:) особенно убило то что сохранение происходит при каждом setProp:) и в нейкие безумные обертки DataOutputStream.. Про ArrayList еслиб там был не String а нейкий класс обертка, то ладно, но тут один String... Вы что в char[](String) пишите безумные DataStream....

Comment: Ну, в принципе, можно `HashMap`. А `DataOutputStream` - я не помню почему, там очень большая программа. Возможно, ошибся. А сохранение при каждом `setProp`, потому что слишком часто писать `myProperties.store(mFileOutputStream, null)..` мне тяжело.

Comment: эм. [`DataOutputStream.writeBytes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeBytes-java.lang.String-) сохраняет символы строки отбрасыванием старших 8 бит. Вы потеряете любые символы с кодом больше 255 в utf-16, в т.ч. русские буквы.